update xlwings with custom addin
how Do I update a custom excel addin made from xlwings?
I updated xlwings package version from 0.24.x to 0.29.x, but now my custom addin (xlam file) still references the old xlwings versions.
How to update my addin file?
tried to update xlwings, yet addin remains not updated. How to update the vba code properly for custom addin?
here is an image added of my vba modules.
enter image description here

The references to xlsings 0.24.9 in your VBA code aren't your problem?
